# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ equals $-\log(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ equals $-\log(1-x)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$. I am taking the following approach but it feels sloppy.

Step #1: I differentiate
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$

Step #2: I use this to conclude that $f(x)$ is equal to the anti-derivative of $1/(1-x)$ -- i.e that $$
f(x) = \int \frac{dx}{1-x}.
$$

Step #3: I integrate to get the desired result
$$
\int \frac{dx}{1-x} = -\int \frac{du}{u} = -\log(u) = -\log(1-x).
$$

The thing that bugs me here is that I'm doing "plug and chug" calculus. For instance, step #2 completely elides the constant of integration. Is the above approach sound?

Comment: What you wrote is not precise, you have to use definite integral.

Just notice that $f(0) = 0$ and therefore $$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(x)dx = \int_0^x \frac{dx}{1-x}$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Hugocito Here's a question about the fundamental theorem. The choice of "0" in the integral seems arbitrary. Is it also the case that $f(x) = \int_a^x f'(x)dx$ for any choice $a$?  Thanks.

Comment: No. Choice of $a$ is not arbitrary. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that
$$f(x) =f(a) + \int_a^x f'(x)dx$$
for any choice of $a$. But if we choose $a=0$ then we have
$$f(x) =f(0) + \int_0^x f'(x)dx.$$

But using the serie describing $f$ we obtain $f(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0^n/n = 0$. Therefore 
$$f(x) =\int_0^x f'(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed incorrect due to neglect of the constant of integration.  From $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ you can conclude that $f(x)$ differs from $-\log(1-x)$ by a constant, not that they are equal.  However, it is easy to determine the constant by plugging in $x=0$, since $f(0)=0=-\log(1-0)$.  So the constant is actually $0$, and $f(x)=-\log(1-x)$.

(Another step that requires justification is that you can differentiate $f(x)$ term-by-term.  This is a standard theorem, though--any power series can be differentiated term-by-term inside its radius of convergence.)